# Why am I getting job ads when it said I wouldn’t?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

When I first signed up to Stack Overflow, I set my job seeking status as “Unemployed, and not currently looking for work”. A box informed be that I would not be receiving job ads on SO. Yet, when I browse the main page, it still advertises companies hiring through SO. Why is this and is there any way I can prevent it? It really clogs up the UI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are just shown in Stack Overflow's "normal" ad section. The option you disabled prevents you from receiving *emails* about these jobs.

When you pass 200 rep, you get to [choose to show less ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).

If you want to remove ads completely, I suggest installing an adblocker.

Comment: Great. Can’t wait to pass 200 :P Will tick in 15 mins after cooldown

Comment: Note that the 200 rep privilege does not hide sidebar ads.

Comment: aww :( back to ublock it is then

Comment: @OliverS. You may be interested in this article from one of the Stack Overflow ad sales team: [Why Stack Overflow Doesn’t Care About Ad Blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/)

Comment: Great. I’ll have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent (most of) it by getting to [200 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). At that level, most ads aren't displayed anymore. Another option would be to install an adblocker.

Comment: I’ll keep that in mind. I turned off my adblocker because 1 I wanted to support SO, and 2 I thought they didn’t have them. I’ll probably put it back on (turns out SO doesn’t get money unless you click through anyway)

Comment: How would not using an adblocker support SO if they didn't have ads? Either you want to support them, or you don't want ads. I guess you could support them with a money donation (or by contributing quality content) and still have ads off.